# How make the register button enable only if password strength is good or strong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the ZXCVBN.js for password strength. It is working as expected. But I want to enable the register button only if the strength of password displays good or strong.

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrdRwk).

```
 var strength = {
 0: "Worst",
 1: "Bad",
 2: "Weak",
 3: "Good",
 4: "Strong"
 }

var password = document.getElementById('password');
var meter = document.getElementById('password-strength-meter');
var text = document.getElementById('password-strength-text');

password.addEventListener('input', function() {
var val = password.value;
var result = zxcvbn(val);

meter.value = result.score;

    if (val !== "") {
text.innerHTML = "Strength: " + strength[result.score]; 
} else {
text.innerHTML = "";
}
});
```

Comment: You are not using AngularJS and why dont you check if `meter.value` is `>=` than 3 and then do what you need

Comment: Hi I am using Angular JS which is given in codepen. It has the entire code if you see it. but I did try what you said it didnt work - I added the following code - if (meter.value>= 3) {
  $("#reg").prop('disabled',true);

Comment: You should read about AngularJS... You are just using javascript inside your codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not using AngularJS. The only Angular thing is the `ng-click` and `ng-model` but you are not even using them. You don't even have a controller.
2. You were checking the strength outside the `EventListener` thus it was only check `onload`.
3. You were using `$('red')` but you don't have `Jquery` in your codepen and you don't have any element with `id : red`. The `id` of the button is `reg`

```js
 var strength = {
   0: "Worst",
   1: "Bad",
   2: "Weak",
   3: "Good",
   4: "Strong"
 }

 var password = document.getElementById('password');
 var meter = document.getElementById('password-strength-meter');
 var text = document.getElementById('password-strength-text');
 var register = document.getElementById('register');

 password.addEventListener('input', function() {
   var val = password.value;
   var result = zxcvbn(val);

   // Update the password strength meter
   meter.value = result.score;

   // Update the text indicator
   if (val !== "") {
     text.innerHTML = "Strength: " + strength[result.score];
   } else {
     text.innerHTML = "";
   }
   if (meter.value >= 3) {
     register.disabled = false;
   } else {
     register.disabled = true;
   }
 });
```

```css
button[disabled] {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zxcvbn/4.4.0/zxcvbn.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
  <meter max="4" id="password-strength-meter"></meter>
  <p id="password-strength-text"></p>

  <button type="submit" ng-click="register()" id="register" disabled>Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @weedoze Thank you for taking time and commenting out and answering. I do have a controller but then I thought why to post it when only html part is required. I did use your answer but it didnt work as expected. I guess I will have to use angular js for it?

Comment: @HebleV If you are using AngularJS why are you using pure JS here ? The code snippet provided is working. It is not working because of some other points in your code obviously. What is not working ?

Comment: Yes you are right. The code snippet is working. Due to some other parts it is not working. So when I use the code, even if i enter a single charcter in password field, the button is getting enabled.

Comment: Could you please accept this answer as it answer your question. Then you can ask another question if you cannot find your problem

Comment: Is that all matters. Accepting an answer than addressing the problem actually

Comment: This is not the only matter but you ask for a problem and I solved it. In the context you are giving us my code is working. You now have another problem link to another part of your code. Try to find the problem yourself and if you cannot you should ask another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126582/discussion-between-heblev-and-weedoze).

Comment: Yes I did ask for a problem and it still exists. It is definitely not another problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can simply change the attribute value of the button element through the javascript or by using jquery to **disabled or active.**Or add some class to button element by using .addClass(classname) property in jquery.
eg.

```
.classname{
disabled:true;
}
```